# Data source io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider does not support streamed writing

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, greenplum

I am trying to read data from kafka and upload it into greenplum database using spark. i am using greenplum-spark connecter but i am getting  Data source io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider does not support streamed writing.
Is it that greenplum source doesnot support streaming data? I can see on the website saying "Continuous ETL pipeline (streaming)".

I have tried giving datasource as "greenplum" and "io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider" into .format("datasource")

```
val EventStream = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", args(0))
  .option("subscribe", args(1))
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .load

val gscWriteOptionMap = Map(
  "url" -> "link for greenplum",
  "user" -> "****",
  "password" -> "****",
  "dbschema" -> "dbname"
)
val stateEventDS = EventStream
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS String)", "*****(value)")
  .as[(String, ******)]
  .map(_._2)

val EventOutputStream = stateEventDS.writeStream
  .format("io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider")
  .options(gscWriteOptionMap)
  .start()

assetEventOutputStream.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Greenplum Spark Structured Streaming

Demonstrates how to use writeStream API with GPDB using JDBC

The following code block reads using a rate stream source and uses the JDBC based sink to stream in batches to GPDB

#### Batch based streaming

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

import scala.concurrent.duration._

val sq = spark.
  readStream.
  format("rate").
  load.
  writeStream.
  format("myjdbc").
  option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/jdbc-checkpoint").
  trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds)).
  start
```

#### Record based streaming

This uses the ForeachWriter

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

import scala.concurrent.duration._

val url="jdbc:postgresql://gsc-dev:5432/gpadmin"
val user ="gpadmin"
val pwd = "changeme"
val jdbcWriter = new JDBCSink(url,user, pwd)

val sq = spark.
  readStream.
  format("rate").
  load.
  writeStream.
  format(jdbcWriter).
  option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/jdbc-checkpoint").
  trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds)).
  start
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of GPDB / Spark are you using?
You could bypass spark in favor of the Greenplum-Kafka connector.

https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5170/greenplum-kafka/overview.html

In earlier versions, the Greenplum-Spark Connector exposed a Spark data source named io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider to read data from Greenplum Database into a Spark DataFrame.

In later versions, the connector exposes a Spark data source named greenplum to transfer data between Spark and Greenplum Database.

Should be something like --

val EventOutputStream = stateEventDS.write.format("greenplum")
      .options(gscWriteOptionMap)
      .save()

See: https://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/160/write_to_gpdb.html

Comment: for spark i am using 2.4.0 and for greenplum "master-0.agent.platform.svc.cluster.local      /greenplum/data-1          PostgreSQL 8.3.23 (Greenplum Database 5.12.0 build dev) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

Comment: for val EventOutputStream = stateEventDS.write.... can't i use val EventOutputStream = stateEventDS.writeStream... ?